# How to Get ECI from ECGI

Tags: gsm, telecommunication, lte

I have ecgi of a lte cell I need to get plmn and and eci out it.
I can  get plmn by doing right shift

plmn = ecgi >>28

I have not idea how to get eci from ecgi.

Answer (score 3):

`ECGI = MCC + MNC + eNodeB id + Cell id`

The latter two are ECI (eNodeB id + Cell id) -> 28 least bits.

That is `ECI = ECGI & 0xFFFFFFF`